# Mixing magnitude phase imaginary real

Tags: python, oop

So I have been working for function that takes two ratios and two component options (magnitude phase real imaginary)
The inputs could be magnitude phase so the result will be new magnitude=ratio1*magnitude_img1+(1-ratio1)*magnitude_img2
Phase=ratio2*phase_img2+(1-ratio2)*pahse_img1
That's what I have reached what I want to decrease the redundancy and make it only two ifs

---

```
@staticmethod
def Mix_Images(img_1: 'Images', img_2: 'Images', component_image_1: str, component_image_2: str, Mix_ratio_1: float, Mix_ratio_2: float):
    """
    Mixes two images by combining their Fourier domain components based on user-specified ratios and components.

    Parameters:
    img_1 (Images): The first image object.
    img_2 (Images): The second image object.
    component_image_1 (str): The component of the first image to use in mixing.
    component_image_2 (str): The component of the second image to use in mixing.
    Mix_ratio_1 (float): The ratio of component_image_1 to mix.
    Mix_ratio_2 (float): The ratio of component_image_2 to mix.

    Returns:
    Mixed_img (np.ndarray): The mixed image as a numpy array.
    """

    # Get Fourier parameters for each image
    Fourier_components = {
        "Magnitude": [img_1.get_component("Magnitude"), img_2.get_component("Magnitude")],
        "Phase": [img_1.get_component("Phase"), img_2.get_component("Phase")],
        "Real": [img_1.get_component("Real"), img_2.get_component("Real")],
        "Imaginary": [img_1.get_component("Imaginary"), img_2.get_component("Imaginary")],
        "Uniform phase": [img_1.get_component("Uniform phase"), img_2.get_component("Uniform phase")],
        "Uniform magnitude": [img_1.get_component("Uniform magnitude"), img_2.get_component("Uniform magnitude")]
    }

    Mix_ratio_1 = Mix_ratio_1 / 100
    Mix_ratio_2 = Mix_ratio_2 / 100

    # Mix the components based on user-specified ratios and components
    if component_image_1 in ["Real"] and component_image_2 in ["Imaginary"]:
        New_real = Fourier_components[component_image_1][0] * Mix_ratio_1 + Fourier_components[component_image_1][1] * (1 - Mix_ratio_1)
        New_Imag = Fourier_components[component_image_2][1] * Mix_ratio_2 + Fourier_components[component_image_2][0] * (1 - Mix_ratio_2)
        Mixed_FT = New_real + 1j * New_Imag
        logger.info(f"Component 1: {component_image_1} and Component 2: {component_image_2} have been selected.")

    elif component_image_1 in ["Imaginary"] and component_image_2 in ["Real"]:
        New_Imag = Fourier_components[component_image_1][0] * Mix_ratio_1 + Fourier_components[component_image_1][1] * (1-Mix_ratio_1)
        New_real = Fourier_components[component_image_2][1] * Mix_ratio_2 + Fourier_components[component_image_2][0] * (1-Mix_ratio_2)
        Mixed_FT = New_real + 1j * New_Imag
        logger.info(f"Component 1: {component_image_1} and Component 2: {component_image_2} have been selected.")

    elif component_image_1 in ["Magnitude", "Uniform magnitude"] and component_image_2 in ["Phase", "Uniform phase"]:
        Mixed_Mag = Fourier_components[component_image_1][0] * Mix_ratio_1 + Fourier_components["Magnitude"][1] * (1 - Mix_ratio_1)
        Mixed_Phase = Fourier_components[component_image_2][1] * Mix_ratio_2 + Fourier_components["Phase"][0] * (1 - Mix_ratio_2)
        Mixed_FT = np.multiply(Mixed_Mag, np.exp(1j * Mixed_Phase))
        logger.info(f"Component 1: {component_image_1} and Component 2: {component_image_2} have been selected.")
    
    elif component_image_1 in ["Phase", "Uniform phase"] and component_image_2 in ["Magnitude", "Uniform magnitude"]:
        Mixed_Mag = Fourier_components[component_image_2][1] * Mix_ratio_2 + Fourier_components["Magnitude"][0] * (1 - Mix_ratio_2)
        Mixed_Phase = Fourier_components[component_image_1][0] * Mix_ratio_1 + Fourier_components["Phase"][1] * (1 - Mix_ratio_1)
        Mixed_FT = np.multiply(Mixed_Mag, np.exp(1j * Mixed_Phase))
        logger.info(f"Component 1: {component_image_1} and Component 2: {component_image_2} have been selected.")

    else:
        st.warning("Invalid Combination")
        logger.warning("Invalid Combination")
        return None

    Image_combined = Images.inverse_fourier_image(Mixed_FT)
    Image_combined = cv2.normalize(Image_combined, None, 0, 255, cv2.NORM_MINMAX, dtype=cv2.CV_8U)
    logger.info("Image combined successfully")
    return Image_combined
```

Comment: Does your code work corectly?

Comment: Yes it does but their is a lot of repetition which is not efficient in backend